# Oozie - Hive action fails for partition table

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am facing an issue with Oozie's Hive action. When I query the Hive table which is partitioned, the Oozie's hive action fails with below error.:

```
 
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'partitions' is unset! Struct:PartitionsByExprResult(partitions:null, hasUnknownPartitions:false)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.PartitionsByExprResult.validate(PartitionsByExprResult.java:389)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.PartitionsByExprResult$PartitionsByExprResultStandardScheme.read(PartitionsByExprResult.java:468)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.PartitionsByExprResult$PartitionsByExprResultStandardScheme.read(PartitionsByExprResult.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.PartitionsByExprResult.read(PartitionsByExprResult.java:359)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_expr_result$get_partitions_by_expr_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:61455)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_expr_result$get_partitions_by_expr_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:61440)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_expr_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:61371)
  at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_partitions_by_expr(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1814)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_partitions_by_expr(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1801)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitionsByExpr(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:828)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.listPartitionsByExpr(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getPartitionsByExpr(Hive.java:1938)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ppr.PartitionPruner.getPartitionsFromServer(PartitionPruner.java:310)
  ... 47 more
```

But when I query different Hive tables which are not partitioned using OOzie's hive action, the workflow run successful.

I have started getting this error since we upgraded hive from 0.11.x to 0.13.1

Comment: Did your hive partition query works without oozie?

Comment: Yes the query work fine on hive cli. Also older version Oozie and Hive 0.11.x Also I tried to set hive.exec.optimize.dynamic.partition.sort=false

Comment: "we upgraded hive from 0.11.x to 0.13.1" => did you upgrade the Oozie ShareLib for Hive actions?

Comment: Thanks a lot Samson Scharfrichter. Upgrading the Oozie ShareLib really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Samson Scharfrichter
I was able to debug this issue. 
The resolution lies on this page 
[Upgrading the Shared Libraries on HDFS](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/)

Check the hadoop fs -ls /user/oozie/share/lib/lib* dir.